# How to install a CLI-only system offline?

Tags: installation, command-line

I would like to install a CLI-only version of the latest Ubuntu (currently 12.04), with as few packages as possible.

(Note: I am **not** looking for stripping down a GUI system -- I want to add the components I need, not remove the components I don't need.)

Which image do I need to download, and how do I proceed to install from that image, assuming I do **not** have a network connection during installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should download the Alternate Installation CD or the Ubuntu Server CD.

If using the Alternate CD, you should be able to press F4 after choosing your language and select "Install a minimal system".

Comment: Hmm I'll try that again, but the last time I looked around I couldn't find that option. (Also: Is this not possible with the regular CD?)

Comment: @Mehrdad You have to press F4 to make the menu appear that contains this option. It is (and has always) been on the alternate CD. You can also use the mini CD for this, though if you have no Internet connection that's not such a good choice because you'll want a CD with lots of packages on it.

Comment: @EliahKagan: Ah, those are great comments, thanks! And yes, I found the option -- it says "install a *minimal* system". I think I was probably looking for the option on a regular CD, which is why I didn't find it originally.

Comment: @EliahKagan: as of 12.04, there is no `-server` kernel any more -- you get the same generic/generic-pae as the desktop version.

Comment: @izx Then what's [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/linux-image-server)?

Comment: @EliahKagan: That's a transitional dummy ackage. Compare to [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/linux-image-server). Hint: no `linux-image-3.2.x-x-server` exists. Read [why](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/TechnicalOverview/Beta2#Ubuntu_Kernel).

Comment: @izx Thx much for the info. (I should've realized that by looking at `linux-image-server`'s dependencies.) So is there different boot/init time kernel configuration between desktop and server 12.04 LTS, or are they really the same with respect to the kernel now?

Comment: @EliahKagan: no difference between minimal server and alternate installs, either grub cmdline wise or in init/upstart that I could see. I even compiled a kernel with no preemption (old "server" setting) and 100 Hz interrupt rate for computational purposes, but saw no noticeable difference (this may vary if a system with such a kernel is also used heavily as a GUI desktop).